# FileWriter writes always in a new line

Tags: java, string, filewriter, bufferedwriter

im having a big problem: I'm trying to write a word or phrase but when my program recieves the phrase, it writes in the file one word per line...

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Hola{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("Pru2.java");
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String palabra = sc.next();

        while(palabra.compareTo("z")!=0){
            bw.write(palabra);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.flush();
            palabra = sc.next();
        }

        bw.close();
    }
}
```

When i write this phrase in the cmd ("This is an example")and then I open the file, this is what i read:

> ```
> This
> is
> an
> example
> ```

I will really appreciate any help!
Thank you very much.

Comment: Err, don't call `newLine()` so often? You shouldn't flush inside the loop either. And don't call files `.java` when they aren't.

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below code helps

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("Pru2.txt");
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String palabra = sc.next();

    while (palabra.compareTo("z") != 0) {
        bw.write(palabra);
        bw.write(" "); //add this line to have space
        //bw.newLine();//comment this line
        palabra = sc.next();
    }
    bw.flush();
    bw.close();
}
```